# XSLT XPath request don't work in a transformation to html

Tags: c#, html, xml, xslt

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<bilans version="1.0">
    <bilan>
        <identite>
            <siren>51515560</siren>
        </identite>
        <detail>
            <page numero="01">
                <liasse code="AF" m1="000000000014381" m2="000000000014381" m4="000000000000750"/>
            </page>
        </detail>
    </bilan>
</bilans>
```

In a xslt transformation to html :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <p>
                    <xsl:value-of select="bilans/bilan/identite/siren/text()"/>
                </p>
            <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 90%; margin: 20px auto; border-width: 2px; border-color: #000000; border-style: solid;" cellpadding="3">
                    <caption style="text-align:center; font-size: 25px; margin-bottom:10px; padding: 5px;color: #000000; border-width: 2px; border-color: #000000; border-style: solid; background-color: #00CED1;">Actif (bilan)</caption>
                    <thead style="text-align:center; font-size: 24px;">
                        <tr>
                            <th style=" width: 70%;  color: #000000; border-width: 2px; border-color: #000000; border-style: solid; background-color: #00CED1">Libellé du poste</th>
                            <th style=" width: 5%;  color: #000000; border-width: 2px; border-color: #000000; border-style: solid; background-color: #00CED1">Code</th>
                            <th style=" width: 15%;  color: #000000; border-width: 2px; border-color: #000000; border-style: solid;background-color: #00CED1 "></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody style="text-align:left; font-size: 17px; color: #000000;">
                        <tr>
                            <td style=" width: 70%; border-width: 2px; border-color: #000000; border-style: solid; ">Capital souscrit non appelé</td>
                            <td style=" width: 5%; border-width: 2px; border-color: #000000; border-style: solid; ">AA</td>
                            <td style=" width: 15%; border-width: 2px; border-color: #000000; border-style: solid; "></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style=" width: 70%; border-width: 2px; border-color: #000000; border-style: solid; ">Frais d'établissement</td>
                            <td style=" width: 5%; border-width: 2px; border-color: #000000; border-style: solid; ">AB</td>
                            <td style=" width: 15%; border-width: 2px; border-color: #000000; border-style: solid; "></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style=" width: 70%; border-width: 2px; border-color: #000000; border-style: solid; ">Frais de développement ou de recherche et développement</td>
                            <td style=" width: 5%; border-width: 2px; border-color: #000000; border-style: solid; ">CX</td>
                            <td style=" width: 15%; border-width: 2px; border-color: #000000; border-style: solid; "></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style=" width: 70%; border-width: 2px; border-color: #000000; border-style: solid; ">Concessions, brevets et droits similaires</td>
                            <td style=" width: 5%; border-width: 2px; border-color: #000000; border-style: solid; ">AF</td>
                            <td style=" width: 15%; border-width: 2px; border-color: #000000; border-style: solid; ">
                                <xsl:value-of select = "/bilans/bilan/detail/page[@numero='01']/liasse[@code='AF']/@m1"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And no value is getting in my table can you help me ? It's in a case of a transformation and i use a c# code to convert the xml with the xslt in a html file and here the xslt complet file. So it's good or you want the c# file with it

this my c# code

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog v1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    OpenFileDialog v2 = new OpenFileDialog();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string output = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/result.html";
    StreamWriter result = new StreamWriter(output);

    v1.Filter = "fichiers XML (*.xml) | *.xml";
    v2.Filter = "fichier xslt (*.xslt) | *.xslt";
    if (v1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if (v2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            XslCompiledTransform mytransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
            mytransform.Load(v2.FileName);
            XsltArgumentList list = new XsltArgumentList();
            mytransform.Transform(v1.FileName, list, result);
        }
    }
}
```

I use a librarie of c# who can convert the xml with a xslt in a html file this is the lib System.Xml.xsl/ System.Xml.linq

Comment: Is that the whole xsl stylesheet? If so, it's missing `xsl:stylesheet` and `xsl:template` tags.

Comment: Your XPath works just fine if I use it in http://xpather.com/ Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @Fildor It's not the whole xsl stylesheet and i have the xsl:stylesheet and the xsl:template tags

Comment: @Filburt my html exit is empty I just have a table with empty cells

Comment: @Sofiane That's why you need to show a complete example of your code - since the XPath works fine, the problem must be either in the Xslt not shown here or in your C# code executing the transformation.

Comment: @Filburt I've edit the question with the complete xslt file

Comment: @Sofiane Also your complete Xslt renders fine when testing in an online tester. Your problem is somewhere else in your C# code.

Comment: Unrelated: You may want to render a CSS style tag into the output HTML ... all those style attributes make it somewhat uncomfortable to read.

Comment: @Filburt I'va had the c# code and thanks for your help

Comment: @Fildor I'm going to upgrade that code

Comment: I'd simplify to [Transform(String, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.transform?view=net-5.0#System_Xml_Xsl_XslCompiledTransform_Transform_System_String_System_String_) and I suspect in your actual code you are suppressing an exception raised by overwriting your existing result.html file.

Comment: @Filburt how i can fix at ?

Comment: Use the [StreamWriter(String, Boolean)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_) with `false` to force overwriting the existing file. However this may still fail if the file is already opened by another process.